# showEvent() called more than once - Intentional?

Tags: qt

What I want to do is display a set of pages setting up a test. Once all the details are correct the user presses Commit and the next wizard page is displayed that I want to immediately run a series of tests in. Displaying those to the user and once complete the user can then click Next.

I know to disable Next is simply a case of returning false on `isComplete()` and that is implemented okay. So, I want to use the function that is called just after the widget is displayed and so I used `showEvent()` which was indicated to me as the function to use.

At the moment my test is just displaying a progress bar as a test hence using a timer.

```
void RunTestWizardPage::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    ui->statusEdit->setText("Running Tests");

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(100);
}

void RunTestWizardPage::update()
{
    static int i = 10;

    ui->statusEdit->append("Running Tests...");

    ui->testProgress->setValue(i++);

    if(i == 100)
    {
        i = 0;
        timer->stop();
        complete = true;
        emit completeChanged();
    }
}
```

However this function appears to be called twice (and I think before the widget display although that may be a trick of my debugging) and as such it causes issues with the timer I think as the timer never ends. I did read in the docs about spontaneous events but from what I can see both calls to the function are not spontaneous.

Is it being called twice intentional and if so how do I stop it or is there another function to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is [`QWizardPage::initializePage()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qwizardpage.html#initializePage) which is called just before showing the page.

Comment: Unfortunately that function is called before the page is displayed so doesn't quite do what is wanted. But from debugging it looks like `showEvent` also is called before the windows is fully displayed